# Filtrar fecha más reciente MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos tengo un SQL y lo estoy trabajando con MYSQL, tengo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT titanes.id, titanes.nombre, titanes.altura, avistamientos.fecha
FROM avistamientos
INNER JOIN titanes
INNER JOIN muertes
ON titanes.id != muertes.id_titan AND titanes.id = avistamientos.id_titan
ORDER BY titanes.altura;
```

Este filtro me funcionó pero me falta de cada titán en avistamientos filtrar solo la fecha más reciente de avistamiento y he probado muchas cosas pero ninguna me ha funcionado hasta ahora.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! CUalquier consulta SQL es correcta dependiendo de lo que desees. Pero, sin saber cuáles son los datos de origen y la salida esperada, está bien difícil decirte algo sobre tu pregunta. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la consulta debe basarse en los titanes y luego obtener la última fecha de avistamiento:

```
SELECT titanes.id, titanes.nombre, titanes.altura, MAX(avistamientos.fecha) AS ultimavisualizacion
FROM titanes
INNER JOIN avistamientos
INNER JOIN muertes
ON titanes.id != muertes.id_titan AND titanes.id = avistamientos.id_titan
GROUP BY titanes.id, titanes.nombre, titanes.altura
ORDER BY titanes.altura;
```

No he podido probar el código pero creo que es una aproximación a lo que necesitas. Agrupando los resultados y aplicando la función `MAX`que devuelve el valor mayor -para una fecha la última vez- creo que te debería funcionar.